# How to properly use system() to execute a command in C++?

Tags: c++, function, system

I am new to C++ programming under Windows. I am trying to execute a command say `cuobjdump` in C++ code using the `system()` function:

```
system("C:\\program files\\nvidia gpu computing...\\cuobjdump.exe --dump-cubin C:\\..\\input.exe");
```

output:

```
Usage  : cuobjdump [options] <file>
```

This followed by the list of the options for cuobjdump.

When I execute this program I always get the cuobjdump help options displayed in the command line. It's as if the system call does not parse the filename. What am I doing wrong? I get the same result while using createprocess. The options `--dump-cubin` gives an error as if I mistyped it.

Comment: At a minimum, you need to make sure you're escaping any backslashes as \\ vs \.

Comment: @kerrek Pls look at my questions. I did not get an answer to some of my questions. :( I will accept one when I see one

Comment: Could you print the exact program output? And also, if you actually use `\\` instead of `\`, please, correct the code (or just copy the exact code).

Comment: Have you tried copying and pasting the text inside the double quotes to a DOS window?

Comment: You see how your questions are able to be answered properly when your question contains the code you are *actually* using?

Comment: @Greg I usually post the code and also some times i am unable to post it for some personal reasons! But I get your point and i totally agree with it!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Give a try with (that is, surrounding cuobjdump.exe path with `"`, properly escaped in C++ as `\"`):

```
system("\"C:\\program files\\nvidia gpu computing...\\cuobjdump.exe\" --dump-cubin C:\\..\\input.exe");
```

Comment: You're welcome :) As another way I think that you could add `cuobjdump.exe` to your `PATH`.

Comment: I already did that. The actual problem was with the file path which had to be put in double quotes and escaped accordingly. :) anyway your tip showed me my oversight! thanks again

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> system("cuobjdump --dump-cubin path\filename.exe");
> ```

That `\f` is interpreted by the compiler as a string escape sequence, try `path\\filename.exe`

Answer (score 4):

Most obviously, `\` is an escape character in C / C++ strings, so it has to be doubled if you want to use it literally.

```
system("cuobjdump --dump-cubin path\\filename.exe");
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `path` is correct, you have to use a double `\\` within strings to represent a single `\`.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) / [ShellExecuteEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) since you are working on Windows. `system` and `ShellExecute` eventually calls `CreateProcess` only.

Comment: The issue was resolved and it turned out that I was missing a double quote. In my original post i mentioned i got the same results with CreateProcess! I was not the downvoter but I thought I should respond to your answer!! :)