# Launching a stand-alone executable from C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exe

I have a programmable signal generator. It came with a .inf file and a .exe file. Double clicking the .exe file runs the signal generator systems application.

I would like to invoke this executable from a piece of VC++ code. I am using Shell Execute as follows.

```
std::string app = "C:\gen.exe";
ShellExecute(NULL,"open",NULL,app.c_str(),NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

However, instead of launching the executable, the command pops open a file dialog.

Upon further experimenting with ShellExecute, I noticed that ShellExecute works for executable files in the Program Files directory, but fails when I have stand alone executables such as in the case I mentioned above. Can someone please explain how to launch using VC++ a standalone executable located in a random directory on the disk?

By Standalone executable, I mean that the binary distribution for the application was simply an executable file, and a couple of other files. I can launch the executable by simply double clicking it, however, I cannot launch it using ShellExecute.

Comment: Don't you get any warning about `\g`?

Comment: Have you tried [CreateProcess](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fwindows%2Fdesktop%2Fms682425(v%3Dvs.85).aspx&ei=2i--UoS6OsbboATR14H4DA&usg=AFQjCNFD-U-wbaFV4sqI7udczMy7BYRTpw)?

Comment: You might want to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672257/using-system-to-execute-a-command-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation for ShellExecute ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), it seems like you might have the reference to `app` in the wrong parameter.  The fourth parameter is the parameters parameter - not the parameter specifying which file to open/run.  So basically, this should work:

```
std::string app = "C:\\gen.exe";
ShellExecute(NULL,"open",app.c_str(),NULL,NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Alternatively, you could use [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or `system("C:\\gen.exe");`.  I should point out that none of these options are portable to other OSs, but running a program probably won't be, however you end up doing it, since most OSs differ on how they run programs - or even what programs are.

Comment: Brian is right about ShellExecute. Interchanging arguments 3 and 4 of my call did the trick. Thanks Brian.

Comment: Also, for someone reading this thread in future, the fifth parameter is used to specify the directory in which your file in located. For me, the file is in my working directory, so I have it set to NULL.

Comment: my sincere apologies. I'll do it right away, still new to here.