# Is there anyway to run a string as a function in C++

Tags: c++

I have a library of Functions and when the user inputs a given string (ie Run x(where x is a program).) the program runs the function.

Full example:
User Inputs: "run chrome"

Program executes: Run(Chrome)
I've searched for answers, and it seems my googling skills are not up to par.

Comment: It's unclear if you want to run a function or a program.

Comment: C++ does not have such a thing, but your OS probably does.  Using Unix, Windows, or other?

Comment: Parse it and compare it to keywords associated with functions (a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`)?

Comment: Perhaps this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672257/using-system-to-execute-a-command-in-c

Comment: Another example would be a Function called Add(x,y). If i had a library full of mathematical functions(ie Divide, subtract, multiply, etc...) it would be inefficient for the user to input what he wants then ask again for the numbers. So in my case i wish the user to enter: "Add 5 and 9". So the program then takes the string of "Add" and then runs it for 5+9.

Comment: What's stopping you from writing C++ code that does exactly what you need? Do you not know how to break this into steps? Is there some step you don't know how to code?

Comment: Yes, the part i do not know how to code is turning a string into a function. I can easily have a string library, then compare the strings, then run the function, but i feel that is too inefficient. instead of comparing the string vs. other strings, cannot it not in itself be converted into a calling for a function. 

Once again, I have a function called Add.
int add(int x, int y)
{
   return x + y
}

Comment: @Xav Use a `std::map` as the previous comment suggested.

Comment: @Xav  *instead of comparing the string vs. other strings, cannot it not in itself be converted into a calling for a function.* -- It still isn't clear what you want.  A `std::map` removes the need for *you* to do the search -- the searching is done internally, and then an association is made to the function / functor that you've defined for that map key.  And as to those other languages suggested in one of the answers, I bet internally those languages are doing the same or similar things, you're just not noticing it.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not directly possible with C++.

C++ does not include a compiler as a part of the language. Lisp and Java among others do, with these langages such a self-compiling program is possible.

With C++ you would have to transform the user input into a suitable source code, invoke a compiler, run the program, and read its output.

Comment: Perfect thank you, Would you then further suggest that I switch to either language? or continue with C++ and run the User Input comparatively

Comment: It depends. If there are just a few functions, a map as suggested in the comments would be easier. And if you don't trust the user, it is not a good idea to compile and run his code. About switching: Calling the compiler should not be very difficult, so I don't see a big advantage in switching. Lisp is something totally different btw.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do would be to use if statements. Unless you have a lot function, it should be enough.

```
if (input == "function1"){
  =function1;
}
else if (input == "function2"){
  function2;
}
```