# What value should Filezilla Server return when programmatically asked to reload its config?

Tags: filezilla

I've tried the following to reload the config in a FileZilla Server after altering its config in a little C++ application:

```c
if (system("\"\"C:\\Program Files\\FileZilla Server\\FileZilla Server.exe\" -reload-config\"") == 0)
{
    // Success
}
else
{
    // Failure
}
```

If I make a valid change, the config appears to be replicated when I subsequently check settings on the server itself but the system call returns `1`.

If I completely corrupt the .xml config file then run the command it still returns `1`.

So is it simply not possible to get a return value indicating whether the config was reloaded?

Comment: Actually it was missing an extra one from the beginning of the command but well spotted. I've updated the snippet.

Comment: I do not think so, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/6672257/850848

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9965141/15369)

Answer (score 0):

The `"FileZilla Server.exe" -reload-config` returns 0 on success and 1 on error.

But the "success" just means that the process sent correctly a "reload configuration" request to the FileZilla Server service. It does not indicate that the configuration was correctly reloaded. There's no way to retrieve that information.

Comment: If that's the case, why does it always seem to return `1` if the config appears to load correctly?

Comment: Even after you added the double-quote?

Comment: Yes even after that.

Comment: No idea, I always get 0. Though I test it from a .bat file like `"C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla Server\FileZilla Server.exe" -reload-config` .. `echo %ERRORLEVEL%`