# How do I copy all tables from one database to another in MySQL for C++

Tags: android, c++, mysql

I want to copy all tables and data in those tables from one database to another in C++ code (not cmd). I want all data to be pasted in my new MySQL database which I connected with a server using their quickstart guide.

The code I found was:

```
CREATE DATABASE copy_of_db;
create table copy_of_db.table LIKE source_db.table;

If you want to copy data too:
INSERT INTO copy_of_db.table SELECT * FROM source_db.table;
```

This isn’t efficient because I have to do this for every table, data and so on. I have to keep reusing this command and I want to do it all at once. I want to copy all data and tables from one database to another. Can someone help me?

Comment: You could execute a mysqldump command from c++. This should be the easiest way

Comment: Can you give me the command @Thallius I’ve been looking everywhere

Comment: [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html)

Comment: @drescherjm it doesn’t show how to do it in c++ it shows cmd

Comment: You can execute that command from `system()`

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672257/how-to-properly-use-system-to-execute-a-command-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672257/how-to-properly-use-system-to-execute-a-command-in-c)

Comment: @drescherjm If I use system command in my android app will it work ? Will the result be the same since it’s from cmd?

Comment: Does not MySql store all tables and data in one file? If so: just copy the file. Or if there are more files: just copy the files.

Comment: Android app? This makes no sense. You develop in C++ on a android device? Are you sure there is a MySQL running and not a SQLite?